# How often can you use the PX-41 serum?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

Early in the game, I received the a ability to use the PX-41 serum. It said it was one use, but others said it has a cool down. How many times can you use it; and if applicable, how long is the cool down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it how many times you want now. It has a cooldown `11 hours` and you can upgrade it like a casual items too, however it costs tokens/marks.